# Macbook 1.1 + Microsoft Bluetooth Notebook 5000 + Win 7 Bootcamp

Tags: bluetooth, boot-camp

Hopefully someone knows the answer to this...

I have an old Macbook 1.1 (snow leopard 10.68) with Win 7 Ultimate in a dual boot (using Bootcamp drivers)...

My Microsoft Bluetooth Notebook 5000 works fine in both operating systems except when I shut down windows...

Every time I start win 7 a box pops up asking for the pairing code (which according to MS is 0000). When I give it the code it comes up with an error and fails to recognize the mouse. So I am forced to remove the mouse from the bluetooth devices list and then re-install the mouse.

Needless to say, this really sucks big time

Anyone got any thoughts

Cheers

T

Answer (score 0):

Basically pairing involves having the input device and computer send recognition codes to each other and then storing them so they can tell the specific devices apart from any other devices which may be in range.  I suspect that since you are pairing the devices to TWO separate OS, the devices are storing the code for OS X and then when you boot Windows, they then need to use the Windows code, but can't store both.  So now you enter the 0000 code and Windows repairs the connection - or attempts to.  The major issue is that the devices can't store and link to two devices.  See similar question same-wireless-mouse-keyboard-logitech-unifying-for-two-different-computers .  There is a keyboard - Logitech K760 that can pair to 3 devices.  I don't know of ANY mice that can multipair right off hand.